# Need help writing js function that changes the class of the button that calls it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not very good with js, but basically I have a button

```
<%=button_to_function "✓", checkButton(), :class => "buttonGrey"%>
```

that is calling a js function I made. However I am getting errors in my syntax for the function.

```
function checkButton()
{
if (this.className="buttonGrey") {
    this.removeClass('buttonGrey');
    this.addClass('buttonGreen');
}

if (this.className="buttonGreen") {
   this.removeClass('buttonGreen');
   this.addClass('buttonGrey');
}
}
```

Comment: this.className="buttonGrey" SHOULD BE this.className=="buttonGrey". Also, it should be `$(this).removeClass` and `$(this).addClass` and if you have jQuery, you should do `if($(this).hasClass('buttonGrey'))`

Comment: What's the actual HTML? How is `checkButton` called?

Comment: Just a quick jQuery tip, you can toggle classes easy with the toggleClass function. ie. this.toggleClass("buttonGreen");  pressing the button will then toggle between grey and green -- it will reduce your code from 8 lines to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `==` to compare `strings` and not `=`.
Your button will always be `buttonGrey` because if it changes on the first `if` statement, it will be changed again on the second because it's not inside a `else` statement.
Also you can use `toggleClass` to toggle classes.

```
function checkButton() {
    $(this).toggleClass("buttonGrey buttonGreen");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a button with 'buttonID' than you can change class like this..

```
$("#buttonID").removeClass("buttonGrey").addClass("buttonGreen");
```

or use toggle function of jquery

```
$("#buttonID").click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("buttonGrey buttonGreen");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Ruby/Rails, but the ideal solution would be to separate the HTML markup from the JavaScript. While you can still use the "onClick" event on the HTML element, it is generally a good practice to give the element an ID and/or Name and then allow JavasScript to bind to that element.

Here is a rough markup of using an ID value:

```
<%=button_to_function "✓", :class => "buttonGrey" :id => "myButton"%>
```

Then in your checkButton() method, update the calls to:

```
function checkButton()
{
if ($("#myButton").className=="buttonGrey") {
    $("#myButton").removeClass('buttonGrey');
    $("#myButton").addClass('buttonGreen');
}

if ($("#myButton").className=="buttonGreen") {
   $("#myButton").removeClass('buttonGreen');
   $("#myButton").addClass('buttonGrey');
}
}
```

Hope that helps, or at least steers you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is partially correct. For comparison, you should be using `==` (`===` is better to use when appropriate).

In the code above though, `this` will not be what you're expecting. In your case it will most likely be the global `window` object. You must pass a reference of the input with the function like so:

```
<%=button_to_function "✓", checkButton(this), :class => "buttonGrey"%>

function checkButton(in)
{
 if (in.className === "buttonGrey") {
    $(in).removeClass("buttonGrey");
    $(in).addClass("buttonGreen");
 }

 if (in.className === "buttonGreen") {
   $(in).removeClass('buttonGreen');
   $(in).addClass('buttonGrey');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the problem is that you are using assignment operator in you if statement

I am not sure what you try to do:

When I write an eventhandler like that i write it like:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
  if ($(this).attr('class') === "buttonGreen") {
     $(this).removeClass('buttonGreen');
     $(this).addClass('buttonGrey');
  }
});
```

To actually getting the button id from asp.net use this code:

```
$('#<%=btnMyButton.ClientID %>').click(function().....
```

Good luck ; )